# Trying to chain together two jQuery functions

Tags: jquery

Attempting to chain two jQuery's together so the second on only happens after the first.

The first function hides a div until it's 250px past the bottom of the viewport.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cta1,#cta2').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInDown',
        offset: 250    
       });   
});
```

The second function animates the button within that div.

```
    $(function(){
    $('.button').animate({"margin-right":"100px"}, 1000);
});
```

My attempt to chain them is...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cta1,#cta2').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInDown', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
        offset: 250    
       }).$('.button').animate({"margin-right":"100px"}, 1000);   
});
```

Code passes Lint, but does not work.

Trying to learn so any help much appreciated!

Comment: Use the `callbackFunction` parameter of `viewportChecker()`.

Comment: ^That's correct. Also note that you can't chain another selector like that you: need to use the likes of http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

With the callbackFunction of viewportChecker you can use your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cta1,#cta2').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInDown',
        offset: 250,
        callbackFunction: function(elem, action){
               $('.button').animate({"margin-right":"100px"}, 1000); 
               // Callback to do after a class was added/ removed to an element.
           } 
       });   
});
```

Furthermore there is a syntax-error in your code. You can't write

```
$('selector').function().$('selector1').function();
```

It has to be:

```
$('selector').function().function();
```

here both function will execute on the Object `$('selector')`

For further reading, have a look [here](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/)

**Reference**

[viewportchecker Options](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker#options)

Comment: I would vote up your answer, but I need a 15 rep to do so. If you hav a moment, I asked a follow-up, and would appreciate any comments you had. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the knowledge! Empiric's code works, but there are two div's and two buttons, so by the time the second div enters the viewport, its button has already animated.

Short of making two functions, one for each div, is there a way to animate the second button only after it parent becomes visible? Maybe something like "if parent is visible, then animate button." Here's my attempt... not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cta1,#cta2').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInDown',
        offset: 250,
        callbackFunction: function(elem, action){
        if (('.button').parent().hasclass('visible')) {
               $('.button').animate({"margin-right":"100px"}, 1000); 
           }
        }
    });   
});
```

Just wish I knew the syntax better!

Comment: pls consider to update your Question instead of adding an answer, could be missleading

Comment: @empiric Just noticed your advice about the follow-up. I was not sure whether to edit, comment or answer! Next time I will edit!